# How to refresh the layout Preview pane in the Android Studio v2.2 IDE?

Tags: android-studio

Older versions of Android Studio had a Refresh option in the layout preview in the IDE, but in v2.2 it has vanished. I am finding repeatedly that I update drawable bitmaps in the project with updated files, that new version is not reflected automatically, and I do not see the preview. Problems like this are so common with Android Studio, it's such an utterly infuriating IDE and so flaky, despite the speed it is advancing.

Where did the refresh option go? I can't believe I'm having to actually ask this, but maybe I missed it somewhere obvious!

Comment: Latest stable version is 2.1.3. Since 2.2 is still in preview, we might need to wait for a stable release to find it fixed.

Comment: FWIW I'm using v2.2 Beta 3. I updated from 2.1x as I was fed up with all the bugs and problems in that.

Comment: We can't expect a preview or beta version to be functioning perfectly :-)

Comment: Sure, but I don't think I've ever used a version of Android Studio that was stable and reliable, even in the Stable channel. Hopefully soon they will be able to add less new features and solidify what is already there.

Comment: 2.2.2 is now officially released, and (unless I am blind) I still can't find the refresh button. Any news regarding this issue ?